# How do I write a contains statement in linq?

Tags: sql, linq, contains

I want to select records where any of the selected fields is a 1.

```
decimal myNumber = 1;
query = from q in query where myNumber.Contains(q.trial, q.score, q.id) select q;
```

in sql I would write

```
select trial, score, id
from query q
where 1 in (q.trial, q.score, q.id)
```

How do I duplicate the sql using linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `array` and use `Contains` method, for sample:

```
var query = from q in query
            where new[]{q.trial, q.score, q.id}.Contains(myNumber)  
            select q;
```

The oposite, when you have many values and you need to compare with an single column, you could do something like this:

```
var myValues = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var query = from q in query
            where myValues.Contains(q.trial)  
            select q;
```

Comment: Does the first example work without putting `new[]{q.trial, q.score, q.id}` in parentheses?

Comment: @ code4life - Well I'll be... `Contains` does not pop up in LinqPad's Intellisense when you write it that way so I thought maybe it did not work.  But I pressed ahead and punched the almighty F5 key anyway.  And what do you know...  Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating a bit more on @Felipe's post:

```
var found = from q in query
    let arr = new []{ q.trial, q.score, q.id}
    where arr.Contains(1)
    select q;
```

**EDIT:** looks like @Felipe updated his post to use dynamically created arrays. I'm going to leave my post in to demonstrate the usage of variables within the LINQ query (`let`). This is useful to know for occasional cases.